# Is this mask-border-slice possible (freeze top & bottom sliver of mask) in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

I am trying to mask a DIV using CSS `mask-border`. Please note that in the real shape the red regions are actually black. I am using the red color to identify the areas of interest as they pertain to my question.

[image]

If I use the mask property straight up (i.e. `mask-border: url('occlude.svg')`) it works as expected, with one caveat: if the DIV I am masking has a different proportion from the mask itself (i.e. mask is 16:9 and DIV is 1:1), then the angles of the top and bottom of my mask change (either become more sharp or more flat). That is expected behavior.

*My question: using the `mask-border-slice` property can I somehow identify that I don't want to rescale the `red` regions of my mask and only scale the black region to grow/shrink vertically as my DIV changes size due to content?*

I've looked through the documentation for `mask-border-slice` and I am able to create some slices, but no combination of syntax seems to work to identify the entire `top` and `bottom` sections as a "slice to keep". Also, FWIW, the `red` regions can be treated as 10% of the entire height. So effectively, going from top to bottom, the image is split up as `10% (red) 80% (black) 10% (red)`.

Any advice on syntax would be greatly appreciated. Or even if this is possible.

If it helps, the SVG of the mask is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 1440 786.2"><path d="M1440 756.2L0 786.2V30L1440 0z"/></svg>
```

Comment: why mask? this is a trivial task with clip-path: https://jsfiddle.net/ha68ft35/

Comment: Thank you. That's a perfect solution!